# PostgreSQL query to select from two tables

Tags: postgresql

there are two table A and B. select from A only if it does not exist in B otherwise select from B. How to write query in postgresql.

Table A
[image]

Table B
[image]

Comment: Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to perform your join of the two tables, and then `COALESCE` to do the logic you like: `SELECT COALESCE(b.f2, a.f2) as f2 FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.f1 = b.f1`  Add sample data and desired results for a more precise answer.

Comment: I want to select all columns from B if exists in B not one column otherwise select from a .. column fields are same in both only data is different.so select all records from B (if exists) else select from a

Comment: In that case, there is no relationship between the tables on which to join. Instead you want `SELECT * FROM TableA UNION SELECT * FROM TableB`. Again... I'm only guessing here. Add some sample data and your desired results otherwise we'll keep going in circles if this doesn't solve your issue. We're flying blind here.

Comment: I added Tables data. I want to select from B if exists there, otherwise A

Comment: @JNevill the union will give both results. I dont want the results to be included from A. there is records in B so want from B only

Comment: Figured as much. Your sample data is lacking still. How do I know that these two records are related to eachother vs the other thousands of records on these tables. Which fields should I anticipate that these two tables will share in common to be able to compare record by record? If your tables each only have one record than this is doable, but if they each have two records, then how do I know which record corresponds in tableA to any particular record in tableB? Is it only Rev_No that will be different? And why do we prefer rev_no of 2 over rev_no of 0? I like 0 as it's not null...

Comment: @JNevill Only rev_no is different all other columns(Property,type,client,year) are same. So we prefer to take whatever rev_no is in table B (if exist) otherwise whatever is in table A.

Comment: Perfect! That's the relationship I was looking for. Awesomesauce. One last question, you say "Table B (if exist)" but in your sample data you have a "0" in that field. Does "0" mean not exist, or in your real table is that set to NULL?

Comment: @JNevill 0 is revision. so its first level revision. Its not null or anything.that column can have values 0,1,2,3. if exist in B means if the record for that particular client,property,year,type exists in B.let me now if need more clarification.

Comment: I see.  I will post an answer that I think will get you in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that I think will get you what you are after. It utilizes a FULL OUTER JOIN and joins on the 4 columns that should relate the two tables together based on *Only rev_no is different all other columns(Property,type,client,year) are same*

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(tableB.Property, tableA.Property) as Property,
    COALESCE(tableB.Type, tableA.Type) as Type,
    COALESCE(tableB.rev_no, tableA.rev_no) as rev_no,
    COALESCE(tableB.client, tableA.client) as client,
    COALESCE(tableB.year, tableA.year) as year
FROM
    tableA
        FULL OUTER JOIN tableB 
            ON tableA.Property = TableB.Property AND
                tableA.Type = tableB.type AND
                tableA.client = tableB.client AND
                tableA.year = tableB.year
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad to hear it! :)